# Typescript: Exclude Property key when starts with target string

Tags: typescript

I want to make new object type from Original type
should be filtered when property key starts with the Target String.

Origin type:

```
type Origin = {
    a: string,
    b: string,
    _c: string,
    _d: string,
}
```

Result type as I want.:

```
// type Result = SomethingWork<Origin, '_'>;
type Result = {
    a: string,
    b: string
};
```

Origin type has dynamic property keys.
so It's not correct, if using type as direct like `'_c' | '_d'`

Comment: You can't do this programmatically, at least as of TS3.1.  You'd need a feature like [regular expression validated string types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) to express "begins with underscore" in the type system.  And that feature doesn't exist currently.  You might want to go that issue in GitHub and give it a  or explain your use case if you think it's more compelling than what's already there.

Answer (score 14):

This is now possible with template literal types

```
type FilterNotStartingWith<Set, Needle extends string> = Set extends `${Needle}${infer _X}` ? never : Set
```

Example:

```
type Origin = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  _c: string,
  _d: string,
}

type FilteredKeys = FilterNotStartingWith<keyof Origin, '_'>
type NewOrigin = Pick<Origin, FilteredKeys>
/*
type NewOrigin = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
*/
```

Comment: You saved my life.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much @Joonas. The inverse is helpful too:


```type FilterStartsWith<Set, Needle extends string> = Set extends `${Needle}${infer _X}` ? Set : never```

Answer (score 8):

I'd like to offer a slight simplification on the existing answer.

```js
type Origin = {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  _c: string,
  _d: string,
}

type OriginWithoutUnderscoreProps = Omit<Origin, `_${string}`>
/*
type OriginWithoutUnderscoreProps = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
*/
```

The inverse for inclusion also works. Note, the `keyof Origin` is needed here because `Pick` has a `keyof` constraint on its second argument whereas `Omit` does not.

```js
type OriginWithUnderscoreProps = Pick<Origin, keyof Origin & `_${string}`>
/*
type OriginWithUnderscoreProps = {
  _c: string;
  _d: string;
}
*/
```

Comment: Woah, didn't know this kind of filtering possible

Comment: For the inverse type, I matched the opposite of `Omit<>` and ended up with `type OriginWithUnderscoreProps = Pick<Origin, Extract<keyof Origin, `_${string}`>>`which I found slightly more readable.

Answer (score 2):

With Respect to @Joonas answer:

```
type KeysStartingWith<Set, Needle extends string> = Set extends `${Needle}${infer _X}` ? Set : never;
type PickByNotStartingWith<T, NotStartWith extends string> = Omit<T, KeysStartingWith<keyof T, NotStartWith>>;

type newOrigin = PickByNotStartingWith<Origin, "_">;
```

Answer (score 1):

can't do it with prefix

but

```
import { ITSDiff, ITSPickMember } from 'ts-type';

export type Origin = {
    a: string,
    b: string,
    _c: string,
    _d: string,
}

export type Result = Pick<Origin, ITSDiff<keyof Origin, '_c' | '_d'>>

let a: Result;

a.a.padEnd(1)

a._c // err
```

---

```
export type OriginOnlyHasPrefix = {
    _c: string,
    _d: string,
}

export type Result3 = Pick<Origin, ITSDiff<keyof Origin, keyof OriginOnlyHasPrefix>>

let a3: Result3;

a3.a.padEnd(1)

// @ts-ignore err when without @ts-ignore
a3._c;
```

Comment: Property keys are dynamic, so cannot use this way. thanks

Comment: @styliss how about cerate a cache type

Comment: I wanted to declare properties on same depth and same object, but i know the it's impossible for this case at now. So I will use way like your second example, thanks