# Typescript - Pick only properties key that starts with a target string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to create a new type from another one, using `Pick` to include specified properties. I've found this: [Typescript: Exclude Property key when starts with target string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501721/typescript-exclude-property-key-when-starts-with-target-string)

I need the opposite.

Origin:

```
type Origin = {
  testA: string,
  testB: string,
  _c: string,
  _d: string,
  example: string,
  anotherName: string,
}
```

Result I would:

```
type Result = {
  _c: string,
  _d: string
};
```

I've tried with

```
type Result = Pick<Origin, `_${string}`>
```

but I got the following error:

```
Type '`_${string}`' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof Origin'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use `Pick` because the second parameter must be `keyof T`, so you can't just

```
type Result = Pick<Origin, `_${string}`>
```

One correct way to handle this is the following:

```
type PickStartsWith<T extends object, S extends string> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends `${S}${infer R}` ? K : never]: T[K]
}
```

This correctly picks only the keys that starts with a prefix:

```
const result: PickStartsWith<Origin, "_"> = {
    _c: "",
    _d: "",
    testA: "", // error
}
```

Here a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgSwOYIHZQLxQN4CgoFTAQDOwAggFxRmKpIA0+hxZAQtbWo8wQPoBjTsDo9CUPgBNhopuIgAPAIYBbMABsIM7nMJLUAe2AALCHAByqrTRE7cAX1y5QkKAAUEAgNYBlYErhgEgB1BBMAHgAVKEViVEkSKAMAIwArCAFgBnc4CAAzBAUYhTiEm1EAPkwcXigAbQBpKDQoLwgQAzyoaKVEptiIeMSAAwASbDdcgoV7cbQ8sygAJXthqAB+KCbqVAgANzMAXWpIxsOHJwEDVDIoXJIAV3Vgag9vPwCg0Ij4ZDRsgBEfABVSweHEgmoAIBun40ig0NhRFIFChMKgAHoMTE4HADHAHEA) link